# Tensorflow with Keras: ValueError - expected dense_84 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 9, 1)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, shapes, valueerror

I am trying to use Tensorflow through Keras to build a network that uses time-series data to predict the next value, but I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_84 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 9, 1)
```

What is causing this? I've tried reshaping the data as other posts have suggested, but to no avail so far. Here is the code:

```
import keras
import numpy as np
import os
from keras import losses
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D, Conv2D

# add the desktop to our path so we can access the data
os.path.join("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop")
# import data
data = np.genfromtxt("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\aapl_blocks_10.csv",
                     delimiter=',')
# separate into inputs and outputs
X = data[:, :9]
X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=2) # reshape (409, 9) to (409, 9, 1) for network
Y = data[:, 9]

# separate into test and train data
X_train = X[:100]
X_test = X[100:]
Y_train = Y[:100]
Y_test = Y[100:]

# set parameters
batch_size = 20;

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=20,
                 kernel_size=5,
                 input_shape=(9, 1),
                 padding='causal'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.3))
model.add(Dense(units=10))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_error,
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# train model
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=batch_size)

# evaluate model
model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=batch_size)
```

And here is the model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv1d_43 (Conv1D)           (None, 9, 20)             120
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_31 (Flatten)         (None, 180)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_14 (Dropout)         (None, 180)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_83 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1810
_________________________________________________________________
activation_29 (Activation)   (None, 10)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_84 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 11
=================================================================
Total params: 1,941
Trainable params: 1,941
Non-trainable params: 0
```

If there's a proper way to be formatting the data, or maybe a proper way to stack these layers, I would love to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need to squeeze the channel dimension from the output, i.e. the labes are shape (batch_size, 9) and you're comparing that against the output of a dense layer with 1 channel which has size (batch_size, 9, 1). Solution: squeeze/flatten before calculating the loss.

```
...
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Flatten())
model.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_error,
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

A note on `squeeze` vs `Flatten`: in this case, the result of squeezing (removing an axis of dimension 1) and flattening (making something of shape (batch_size, n, m, ...) into shape (batch_size, n*m*...) will be the same. Squeeze might be slightly more appropriate in this case, since if you accidentally squeeze an axis without dimension 1 you'll get an error (a good thing), as opposed to having your program run with unexpected behaviour. I don't use keras much though and couldn't find a 'Squeeze' layer - just a `squeeze` function - and I'm not entirely sure how to integrate it.